# creating buttons using a while loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a modal dialog that should display a field of my SQL query result for example I'll run

```
select * from users where salary IS NULL;
```

I want to create a button with the users who have no salary set
I should be getting 
adel
ahmed
as buttons on the modal dialog
here's my code:

```
if ($rows > 0) {
                echo "some employees have not been assigned an hourly rate yet"; ?>
    <br>        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="set salaries" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#salaryModal"/>
          <div class="modal fade" id="salaryModal" >
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group ">
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($auth)) { 
                $username = $row["username"]; ?>

                  <input class="btn btn-success" onclick="sayHello()" id="calculate_salary_button" value="<?php echo $username;} ?>"/></a> <br>

                </div>
                <?php } } ?>
```

outside the modal dialog, I echo the usernames coorectly, here however I get one button:

adel

Comment: You got a `}` in your `value="<?php echo $username;} ?>"` which ends the while loop after the first run. - And ID's must be unique.

Comment: yup :D that solved it thankyou

Comment: post that as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a `}` in your

```
value="<?php echo $username;} ?>"
```

Which ends the while loop after the first run.

And your `input` fields ID's must be unique